# ffmpeg default audio codec instead of specifying it with acodec option

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, codec, pcm

In raspberry pi I've following [i2s](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-i2s-mems-microphone-breakout/raspberry-pi-wiring-test) microphone breakout board and use it like the guide suggested. When I try record audio from it using ffmpeg to the file with `ffmpeg -f alsa -i dmic_sv out.wav` command. I'll receive following error

```sh
[alsa @ 0x22e21c0] cannot set sample format 0x10000 2 (Invalid argument)
dmic_sv: Input/output error
```

When I specify the used codec explicitly with `-acodec` it works fine:

```sh
ffmpeg -f alsa -acodec pcm_s32le -i dmic_sv out.wav
```

And from the output ffmpeg will reencode to `pcm_s16le`

```sh
Input #0, alsa, from 'dmic_sv':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1597597938.887969, bitrate: 3072 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s32le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s32, 3072 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s32le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
```

How I can tell ffmpeg to use signed 32-bit little endian by default without specifying it explicitly? And where ffmpeg gets this default and can I configure it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this one out myself by reading ffmpeg source code. It seems when codec is not specified and alsa device is used. FFmpeg will default to pcm 16-bit samples instead. Code to set the default [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/2ff3c466eca66bb8eb32bb41a4ce70fe285e3ea0/libavdevice/alsa.c#L183) and the default macro [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/2ff3c466eca66bb8eb32bb41a4ce70fe285e3ea0/libavdevice/alsa.h#L42).